# Call a method as a field of ValuesQuerySet

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I have a model and a method on it as follows:

```
class Results(models.Model):
    t_id = models.TextField(blank=True)
    s_result_id = models.TextField(blank=True,primary_key=True)
    s_name = models.TextField(blank=True)
    s_score = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    ... (some other fields with huge data)
    def get_s_score(self):
        return 100 * self.s_score
```

On a view, I am trying to call get_s_score method from inside values. I have to use values to avoid selecting other fields with huge data.

```
    def all_recentsiteresults(request,t_id1):
Result = Results.objects.filter(t_id=t_id1).values('s_result_uid','s_name',get_s_score())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use the model's method in the `values()` method.  But you can use the [`only()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.only) method to decrease the memory usage:

```
Results.objects.only('s_result_id', 's_name', 's_score').filter(t_id=t_id1)
```